# x-ray - Check if content of td is equal to a value

Tags: node.js

I'm learning web-scraping with node.js x-ray. I am fetching a list of proxies from a website's table. For every row in a table, I want to check if `td:nth-child(7)` is equal to 'no' or 'yes'. I wanna create a property in the object called `_proto`, with the value of `true` if `td:nth-child(7)` is 'yes' else `false`;

So far this is my code:

```js
xray("https://free-proxy-list.net/", '#list tbody tr', [{
    ip: 'td:nth-child(1)',
    port: 'td:nth-child(2)',
    code: 'td:nth-child(3)',
    country: 'td:nth-child(4)',
    anonymity: 'td:nth-child(5)',
    google: 'td:nth-child(6)',
    https: 'td:nth-child(7)'
}])((err, proxies) => {
    console.log(proxies);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution looks like this:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray')
var x = Xray()

x("https://free-proxy-list.net/", '#list tbody tr', [{
  ip: 'td:nth-child(1)',
  port: 'td:nth-child(2)',
  code: 'td:nth-child(3)',
  country: 'td:nth-child(4)',
  anonymity: 'td:nth-child(5)',
  google: 'td:nth-child(6)',
  https: 'td:nth-child(7)'
}])((err, proxies) => {
  proxies.map(proxy => {
    if (proxy.https === 'yes') { 
      proxy._proto = true
    } else {
      proxy._proto = false
    }
  })

  console.log(proxies)
});
```

After getting the proxies list, the callback function checks if any of the proxy objects has a property called “https” set to “yes”. If that’s the case, it adds a new property called “_proto” and sets it to true and if that’s not the case, it adds the “_proto” property but sets its value to “false”.
In the end it console logs the new list that contains the “_proto” properties.

Let me know if this works for you and good luck on your way to mastering web scraping!